# Overriding CSS that uses a :not Selector

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a custom Bootstrap theme, and wanted to create a new class for certain tables. The original CSS has the following line:

```
table a:not(.btn), .table a:not(.btn) {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Later, I've added my own custom CSS, to remove the underline from links:

```
.gridview a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table gridview">...
```

Using Chrome's developer tools, I can see that my `gridview` class is loaded *after* the original table class, yet it is being overridden by the original. I've also experimented by replacing my CSS with the following:

```
table a, .table a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

...but I'm getting the same result. There are likely a few workarounds I could use (such as `!important` if it really came to it), but I'd like to understand what's going on first and hopefully come up with a cleaner solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Read this: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Comment: Very useful link, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we examine both:

```
.table a:not(.btn)
C      T:S

.gridview a
C         T
```

There is a little more specificity in the bootstrap's selector. The pseudo class selector is more specific. So changing your class to this way:

```
.gridview a, .gridview a:not(.btn)
```

Will make it work. Or to be more specific, you can give all the values:

```
table.gridview a:not(.btn), .table.gridview a:not(.btn)
```

Comment: @MichaelMcMullin Sorry I didn't explain, if you ask: `C` is Class Selector, `T` is Tag Selector, and `S` is specific selector.

Answer (score 3):

It's about Specificity.

```
.some_div .another_div a {color:#000;}
```

is more specific than

```
.another_div a {color:#fff;}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

You should arrange it again with a higher specific selection

```
.some_div table a, .some_div .table a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar I disagree. An answer can contain directions to or specifics about what has to be done but can omit exactly how it needs to be done, due to any good reason (no single correct answer, boiler-plate answer, too obvious answer, etc). Source: [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @klaar He edited the answer!!! I have removed the downvote. Check how it was before!

Comment: @klaar http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1e31fbf5-bf87-467e-95d7-adca14983462/view-source

Comment: @PraveenKumar I am aware of that, but that is not my point. What he said in his original answer contained both the cause to OP's issue and also the necessary information to come to a working alternative. I agree that the answer is not very direct, meaning that the OP has to read a lot before coming to the required conclusion, but imo that is "the way of the noob" (meaning you cannot avoid the need to actually know about things to use those things properly), alas!

Comment: @klaar Anyways, I removed my downvote. `:)` I removed my comment too.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
table.gridview a:not(.btn), .table.gridview a:not(.btn) {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[More information about css selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)

[image]